# InverseFunction of ArcTanh and Log

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities, integral-equations, boundary-condition-at-infinity, inverse-function

I solved an equation and one solution was this:

```
f[a_] := Log[6] + Log[2*a + Sqrt[-2 + 4.1*a^2]] 
          - 2*ArcTanh[(a*0.5)/Sqrt[-2 + 5*a^2]]
          - Log[-1 + 2*a^2]

InverseFunction[f[a], a]
```

I used `InverseFunction[&]` but it is not doing anything!

Comment: What is the question?  If `A`, `B` and `F` are not specified you will not be able to plot the solution. Otherwise you should not expect a simpler form of the solution. Nevertheless you can approximate locally a symbolic solution with help  of expanding it in a Taylor series or finding a Pade approximant with `PadeApproximant`.

Comment: You can consider A=0.6 ,B=0.3 and F=0.002

Comment: Edit your question to include the code for the `InputForm` of the expression so that we can copy and paste the code into a notebook. Also put the info about the values for A, B, and F in the question rather than a comment.

Comment: Please review again. Thanks :)

Comment: Try to copy and paste from your question into a notebook. Doesn't work. Convert your cell to `InputForm` then copy and paste into your question and format as a code block. Also, note that the definition for `f` should include a pattern on the LHS, i.e.,`f[a_] := ...`

Comment: Actually, it was the same but I changed the way you said.

Comment: The expression in your question is not in `InputForm` and cannot be copy and pasted into a notebook. Try it. In your notebook select the cell and use the menu command `Cell | Convert To | InputForm` or the corresponding shortcut with your OS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131115/discussion-between-user199315-and-bob-hanlon).

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for [`InverseFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFunction) was wrong, it should be something like:

```
InverseFunction[f][x]
```

For example:

```
Plot[InverseFunction[f][x], {x, 1, 3}, PlotRange->All]
```

[image]

You will notice that there are values of `x` for which [`InverseFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFunction) has trouble. In this case it helps to put a restriction on the range using [`ConditionalExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression):

```
Plot[
    InverseFunction[ConditionalExpression[f[#], #>.8]&][x],
    {x, 1, 3},
    PlotRange->All
]
```

[image]

Comment: The last figure is not coming out from my Mathematica!!!