# Inverse VS Reduce

Tags: equation-solving, inverse, inverse-function

I got a solution I want to get inverse but it is not working in Mathematica or Rubi:

```
f[x_] := (a*ArcTanh[(a*x)/Sqrt[-d + b*x^2]])/(a^2 - b)(Sqrt[b]*ArcTanh[(Sqrt[b]*x)/Sqrt[-d + b*x^2]])/(a^2 - b) + (a*Log[d + (a^2 - b)*x^2])/(2*(a^2 - b)); 

InverseFunction[(a*ArcTanh[(a*x)/Sqrt[-d + b*x^2]])/(a^2 - b) -(Sqrt[b]*ArcTanh[(Sqrt[b]*x)/Sqrt[-d + b*x^2]])/(a^2 - b) + (a*Log[d + (a^2 - b)*x^2])/(2*(a^2 - b)), x]

Reduce[y == f[x], x]
```

All parameters are positive.

Comment: Probably you consider a real function? If yes,  `FunctionDomain[f[x], x, Reals]` shows several necessary conditions which must be fullfilled. Without further restriction Mathematica cannot evaluate the ` InverseFunction`

Comment: Duplicates: [(257680)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/257680), [(257851)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/257851) -- You make the same syntax error in `InverseFunction` above as was corrected for you in [(257680)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/257680).

Comment: What makes you think this equation/inverse can be solved symbolically?